# Why in codeignitor 3 mysqli update query taking more then 20 seconds

Tags: codeigniter-3, mysql-slow-query-log

while debugging when I reach on this point it took some time more then minute.

```
$this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        $this->db->update('tbluser', ['activity' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

I have executed same update query string in phpmyadmin and it took 0.0005 seconds. Don't know why it is like that, anyone help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.  (Codeigniter is one of a hundred frameworks; most of us don't know its details.)

Comment: UPDATE `tbluser` SET `activity` = '2022-11-29 02:06:23' WHERE `tbluser`.`userid` = 27;

Comment: The query, by it self, looks OK.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbluser`.  Also, was a backup (or some other big thing) going on?